# Can't make full screen application for "Galaxy Tab" (Android device)

Tags: android, tabs, galaxy

Can anyone tell me, even though I set the below listed tags in my AndroidManifest.xml file, why I can't make my application run as full screen on the "Galaxy Tab" (Android device)? I am developing my current application with 2.3 Api level 9.

Here is the tag I have defined in my Manifest.xml file :

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
                android:targetSdkVersion="9" android:maxSdkVersion="9" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are using, uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" in your manifest file.

if u want to show it as full screen in Galaxy tab. Use the minSdkVersion greater than 3
its better to use

Let me know if u have any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry ya.. better to use uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"

Answer (score 1):

make the target sdk as level 11 or above because honeycomb starts with level 11.

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application element in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```